# Div size is not size according to its content with display: inline-block;

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="itemOne">
        <img src="banana.jpg" />
        <h1>0.89$ per kg</h1>
        <input type="button" class="addToCart" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #272727;
}

.itemOne{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.itemOne img{
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
}

h1{
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP0oS.png)

It doesn't want to make div size fit content on div
I tried everything maybe its because of the picture because without it worked but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I am not able to get the issue, can you please also share expected behaviour

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's completely not understandable. Please explain more or upload the photo that you wish looks like that.

Comment: I think that the issue is that the OP wanted to have image inline with the text and the button. Is that right OP? The problem there is that the display: inline-block of the parent is not what will work. The H1 element is a block element and it will go to the new line. What you can do is set the display: inline to the H1 element. But a better solution would be if you used display: flex on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `width: 30%` and `height: 50%` for your `<img>` but you didn't specify how wide and tall the `.itemOne` is, so the browser takes 30% as 30% of the size of your original image.

Here are some solutions to your problem:

**SOLUTION 1** - set `width` for `.itemOne` and set `width: 100%` for `.itemOne img`:

```css
body{
    background: #272727;
}

.itemOne{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 30%;
}

.itemOne img{
    width: 100%;
}

h1{
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemOne">
        <img src="https://auto1-homepage.prod.mp.auto1.cloud/static/optimized/blue-car-hp-left-bmw.png" />
        <h1>0.89$ per kg</h1>
        <input type="button" class="addToCart" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart" />
    </div>
```

**SOLUTION 2** - set fixed `width` for your `.itemOne img`:

```css
body{
    background: #272727;
}

.itemOne{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.itemOne img{
    width: 300px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemOne">
        <img src="https://auto1-homepage.prod.mp.auto1.cloud/static/optimized/blue-car-hp-left-bmw.png" />
        <h1>0.89$ per kg</h1>
        <input type="button" class="addToCart" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a percentage for `width` and `height`, the pixel size of the image in the DOM stays *unchanged*. Only its appearance is reduced, and the `<div>` scales so it can fit the original image.

The fix is to specify an exact `width` and/or `height` for the image, as in this example, with a 400x300 image scaled back to a width of `150px`:

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.itemOne {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.itemOne img {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemOne">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" />
  <h1>0.89$ per kg</h1>
  <input type="button" class="addToCart" value="Add to cart" id="addToCart" />
</div>
```